# Get all files with a certain pattern c++ linux vs. windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-platform

I'm trying to get all of the file with a certain pattern from a specific directory.
**for example "ia_aiq_usecase_*.bin" from "c:\temp"**

my windows code works fine. 
however in linux I do not want to use boost. and I can't seem to find a way to get all the files with a certain pattern. 
Can you please help ?

Is there a way to do it cross platform?

```
const std::vector<std::string> OS::GetAllFiles(std::string directoryPath, std::string filePattern)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    std::vector<std::string> files;
    std::string pathAndPattern = directoryPath + OS::PathSeperator() + filePattern;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFile(ToWString(pathAndPattern).c_str(), &fd);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
     {
        do
        {
            if (!(fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
            {
                files.push_back(FromWString(fd.cFileName));
            }
        } 
        while (::FindNextFile(hFind, &fd));
        {
            ::FindClose(hFind);
        }
    }
    return files;
#else
    std::vector<std::string> files;
    std::string search_path = directoryPath + OS::PathSeperator() + filePattern;
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    if ((dp = opendir(directoryPath.c_str())) == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << directoryPath << std::endl;
        return errno;
    }

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        files.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));
    }
    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
#endif
}
```

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?  C++14 has experimental support for file systems and it is included in the upcoming C++17 standard.  Also there is `boost::filssystem`

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097, which has many creative solutions.

Comment: @NathanOliver gcc 4.8.1

Comment: @UlfLunde I need a file pattern.

Comment: Given a list of all files in the directory, you can match them to the pattern yourself.  (I'm not saying there is no cross-platform way to fetch a pattern-matched list of files, I have no idea whether there is or not.  I'm just saying that you don't *need* that functionality.)